# Javascript form checked and not showing element after

Tags: javascript, html

I really need help for something very basic in Javascript. I have a form and what I want is that if the radio button is selected, the next question will display. I think that I need to use the 'If Else' block but I don't know where it is wrong.

Javascript code:

```
 function stageofproject() {
    if (document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked = true) {
       document.getElementById("project").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else (document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked = false) {
       document.getElementById("project").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    }
    }
    stageofproject();
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
                <legend>Ik wil mij aanmelden:</legend>
                <li><label>
                    <input type="radio" name="submit-for" value="project" id="vooreenproject">
                    <span>Voor een project</span>
                </label></li>
                <li><label>
                    <input type="radio" name="submit-for" value="stage" id="alsstagebedrijf">
                    <span>Als stagebedrijf</span>
```

Can somebody check what I do wrong?

Comment: where  is `project`  in html ?

Comment: First of all, you should fix your code first, comparisons must be done with `==` or `===`, I would go for `===` rather than `==` because if no type conversion would about occur, [see here for more info](http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/). Also, setting style through script should be avoided. Try switching classes if possible.

Comment: To save pain from writing so much code for these tiny tasks, i recommend you to use some external `js` libraries for traversing and manipulating `DOM`. There are plenty of them so i would not name one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You will need `change` listener. Also use `===` or `==` for comparison. `=` will assign the `Boolean` value to the element.

```js
function stageofproject() {
  if (document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("project").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else if (document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked == false) {
    document.getElementById("project").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Ik wil mij aanmelden:</legend>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" checked name="submit-for" value="project" id="vooreenproject" onchange="stageofproject()">
      <span>Voor een project</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="submit-for" value="stage" id="alsstagebedrijf" onchange="stageofproject()">
      <span>Als stagebedrijf</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</fieldset>
<div id="project">Question here</div>
```

Comment: This will not work for second case html..hardcoded id

Comment: @Navoneel, Did not get you. Second case ?

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="submit-for" value="stage" id="alsstagebedrijf" onchange="stageofproject()">` ?but in stageofproject function id is hardcoded.something like this `onchange="stageofproject(this)"` then `document.getElementById(this.id).style.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: @Navoneel, How does that make a difference ? ID of radio element is not referred anywhere..

Comment: kindly note in the js `document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked` .here vooreenproject is the first radio button id.

Comment: @Navoneel, You spotted it right but as they are RADIO buttons, only one element from the group will be checked hence it will work as OP is expecting! Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: **"Also `==` was wrong for comparison"**, how can you say that, besides you are using `==` in your code!!

Comment: This one really worked for me, thank you @RayonDabre!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need two equal signs to check for equality:

```
function stageofproject() {
  if (document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked == true) {
     document.getElementById("project").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked == false) {
     document.getElementById("project").style.visibility = "hidden";       
    }       
  }
  stageofproject();
```

Comment: **else (document.getElementById("vooreenproject").checked == false) {**

Answer (score -1):

add a `onclick` attribute then place the `stageofproject()` function inside

```
<input onclick="stageofproject();" type="radio" name="submit-for" value="project" id="vooreenproject">

<input onclick="stageofproject();" type="radio" name="submit-for" value="stage" id="alsstagebedrijf">
```